# Authenticating Users with Email & Password error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

Im trying to create a mail and password user to firebase, but im kepp getting this error:

> Error: The browser redirected the page before the login request could complete. {code: "REQUEST_INTERRUPTED", stack: (...), message: "The browser redirected the page before the login request could complete."}

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://***.firebaseio.com");
$('.btn').click(function() {
   var mail = $('#inputEmail3').val();
   var pass = $('#inputPassword3').val();
   ref.createUser({
       email : mail,
       password : pass
    }, function(error) {
       if (error === null) {
        console.log("User created successfully");
       } else {
        console.log("Error creating user:", error);
       }
   });
});

$(document).ready();
```

Comment: I wonder shouldn't the click handler end with `return false`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the element you are selecting with the `$('.btn')` selector is a link the browser will navigate to the linked page before the asynchronous `ref.createUser` function completes. To prevent this, add a `return false` statement to the end of the click event handler. You can also add an `e.preventDefault()` statement at the top of the click handler which will ensure that the link navigation does not occur as shown below.

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) { //Add the 'e' event object to the parameters
    e.preventDefault() //Prevents navigation (the default link click action)
    var mail = $('#inputEmail3').val();
    var pass = $('#inputPassword3').val();
    ref.createUser({
        email : mail,
        password : pass
    }, function(error) {
       if (error === null) {
        console.log("User created successfully");
       } else {
        console.log("Error creating user:", error);
       }
   });
   return false; //Extra insurance
});
```